# How to deploy Storm, Zookeeper, and Supervisor nodes to GCP?

Tags: docker-compose, google-compute-engine, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm, google-cloud-build

We're trying to set up a Storm cluster with Google Compute Engine but are having a hard time finding resources. Most Tutorials only cover deploying single applications to GCE. We've dockerized the project but don't know how to deploy to GCP. Any Suggestions?

Comment: by GKE is suitable for your project? because from the gitlab official page[1] there is a guide how to implement in K8s they pulled the official image from the docker-hub[2]. I did not mark this as answer cos your request is for GCE; I think you can manually use a cluster of image- container on GCE and setup the storm by hand, but well the deploy isntruction on k8s are easier/practical implementation way. Hope it can be useful. 

[1]https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/storm
[2]https://hub.docker.com/_/storm

Answer (score 0):

You may try to configure an [instance template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/) and create instances with [COS image](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/) which already have Docker installed.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#advantages) you can have more information about this.

Other option is using Kubernetes Engine (GKE) which has more features that can help you to have more control on your workloads and it also supports autoscaling, auto upgrades and node repairs.